# MassTransit ServiceBus message marked as complete during failure

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

Where does MassTransit mark servicebus messages as complete? e.g. the message was successfully processed and can be removed from the queue.

We have seen examples where a failure happens in a filter (before the consumer is created) and the message is marked as complete. It does not get redelivered, never shows up in dead-letter, and disappears from the queue. I have stacktraces and more context, but I'd prefer to see the source code first.

Edit -
I'm looking for the Complete operation on the BrokeredMessage. For azure Functions, MT documentation indicates that the complete operation is automatically handled by function runtime. My consumer is running in a console app so I am looking for the source file where that complete operation is called.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.complete?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit) is available. You'd need to add significantly more information to your question before any type of answer could be formulated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- *There are few **exceptions** while using the **Mass Transit** and from that one is redelivery and for that you can use a scheduled redelivery option and below is the source code for using **Scheduled Redelivery***

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseDelayedRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
        cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

- *The above code will help you in redelivering the message 5 retries initially and if it fails after every **15 to 30 minutes tries again to send for 5 times**. That means a 15 retires
- *Check the [Mass Transit Exceptions](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#redelivery) Document for complete information.**
  [image]
- *Also, as suggested by [**Chris Patterson**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1882/chris-patterson) you can even have a look of Mass Transit Source [**documentation**](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit).*